# Adding "Max Length" to Regex

Tags: c#, regex

How can I extend already present Regex's with an attribute telling that the regex can't exceed a maximum length of (let's say) 255?

I've got the following regex:

`([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)`

I've tried it like that, but failed:

`{.,255([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)}`

Comment: Check the length of the matched result?

Comment: `{.,255}` After the expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best way of doing this, if it has to be a solely regex based solution, would be to use lookarounds.

View this example: http://regex101.com/r/yM3vL0

What I am doing here is only matching strings that are at most *three* characters long. Granted, for my example, this is not the best way to do it. But ignore that, I'm just trying to show an example that will work for you.

You also have to anchor your pattern, otherwise the engine will just ignore the lookaround (do I have to explain this in depth?)

In other words, you can use the following in your regular expression to limit it to at most 255 characters:

```
^(?!^.{256})([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)
```

I also feel it is my duty to tell you your regular expression is bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: +1, you're perfectly right, of course. I've removed the regex entirely. But nevertheless your post has helped me understanding regex's better :) Thanks for that!

Comment: No problem! Check out the quiz on http://www.regex101.com/quiz/ if you want to understand regexes even better :)

Answer (score 1):

A regex is not really made to solve all problems.  In this case, I'd suggest that testing a length of 255 is going to be expensive because that's going to require 255 states in the underlying representation.  Instead, just test the length of the string separately.

But if you really must, you will need to make your characters optional, so something like:

```
.?{255}
```

Will match any string of 255 or fewer characters.

Comment: But will allow anyone to put 255 random characters in front of your emailaddress!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check for Max Length of the string as well? If you're using DataAnnotations, you can stick [StringLength(255)] on the property.

If you're using ASP.NET Validators, you can use a RangeValidator.

If you're using a custom validation function it's much more readable (and faster) to check the length before you throw a complex regex against it.

Answer (score 1):

You "may" be able to use a look-ahead as follows:

```
^(?=.{0,255}$)your regex here$
```

So...

```
^(?=^.{0,255}$)([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Comment: i was looking so long for this. Thanks Loads!