# Need Regular expression for Validating and Restricting Length of EmailID

Tags: asp.net, regex

Need Regular Expression for Validating Proper Email and Restricting Its Length to 150 Characters. Currently I'm using Following Expression for Validating Proper

EmailID

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

How to add Length Validation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?=.{5,150}$)\w+([-.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/GiWhnSbXvr)

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this for checking lenght

```
^(?=.{0,150}$)your regex here$
```

For you

```
^(?=.{0,150}$)\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

you can check same on : [stackoverflow.com/questions/13923652/adding-max-length-to-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923652/adding-max-length-to-regex)

---

you can try like this

```
^\d{1,45}$
```

this limit lenght of character

not sure but you can do like this

```
[\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*]{1,150}$
```

Some more information about lenght

Depending on what implementation of regex you're using, you can specify ranges with curly braces. eg

```
{5} -- exactly 5
{5,} -- at least 5, no upper limit
{5,10} -- at least 5, no more then 10
```

Comment: I need to have both Validations . In this case what will be my Regular expression

Comment: Thank you for Replying ,It is Giving me this error parsing "[\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*]{1,150}$" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

System

   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanCharClass(Boolean caseInsensitive, Boolean scanOnly)